# Building a Universal Windows driver (UMDF 2) results in link error

Tags: windows, wdk, umdf

while following the tutorial on writing a Universal Windows Driver (UMDF 2) based on template ([link to MSDN Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439659(v=vs.85).aspx)) I get the following error trying to build with no modifications to the template code.

> Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\wpprecorderum.lib'

I installed the latest windows 10 WDK from here ([link to WDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)) and have found this file exists at: C:\Program Files (x86)...\lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64\ NOT C:\Program Files (x86)...\lib\10.0.1024.0\um\x64...

When I change the Windows Target version from 10.0.1024.0 to 10.0.10586 I get the error

> Error     An SDK corresponding to WDK version '10.0.10586.0' was not found.

How do I get this to compile? Do I need to find an earlier version of the WDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the tutorial should state that you need the latest version of the windows SDK as well. So here is link ([Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)). Once I installed that the build was successful.